# How to inline few java lines inside an Ant script?

Tags: java, ant, heredoc

How to inline (here-document) few java code lines into a Ant script ?
Please an example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe you can sensibly do it for actual Java code, but I've had a lot of success doing this with [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/). The [Groovy Ant task documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) is pretty good. For example:

```
<groovy>
xmlfiles = new File(".").listFiles().findAll{ it =~ "\.xml$" }
xmlfiles.sort().each { println it.toString() }
</groovy>
```

(You can write Groovy in a much more Java-like fashion if you want to.)

Answer (score 7):

You can add any [BSF](http://jakarta.apache.org/bsf/) capable language to Ant, using the [<script>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) tag, including Javascript, Groovy, JRuby etc.

The most *Java-like* of these is [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/), and is probably what you want.